# Creating a 3d matrix with pandas panel

Tags: python, csv, pandas

My goal is to create a pandas panel, I currently have a csv, with the sample as follows:

```
Year From country            To country  Points
2005      Albania               Albania       0
2005      Albania  Bosnia & Herzegovina       0
2005      Albania               Croatia       2
2005      Albania                Cyprus       7
2005      Albania               Denmark       0
```

I want to make a 3D array where the first axis is all the years range, which I have to search through the csv to find when 2005 turns to 2006, etc then the next axis will be the from country and the other axis will be the to country, and those axes will have the value of points... if that makes sense? Is the pandas panel the tool I should be using here, and how would scrape the years from the big dataframe to create a new dataframe for assumingly, all the years (2005 - 2016)

EDIT:
I found this picture, which is exactly what I'm trying to do for EACH year instead of the average of all the years. So it'd be like have one of those graphs for each year, 2005 - 2016
[image: matrix]

Answer (score 0):

Format your dataframe where the index is a multiindex with two levels.  Using the method `to_panel` will assume the `Items` is in the columns, `Major_axis` is in the first level of the index, and `Minor_axis` is in the second level of the index.

```
df.set_index(['From country', 'To country', 'Year']).Points.unstack().to_panel()

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 2005 to 2005
Major_axis axis: Albania to Albania
Minor_axis axis: Albania to Denmark
```

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. And I do not know how to change what you have to work. Also why is the .Points. there?